# Row Independence Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I was watching some of Dr. Gil Strang's Lecture, when I came upon an interesting question.

In the lecture, Dr. Strang was discussing how to find the nullspace of the rows of a matrix, A. In other words, this method determines whether the rows of a matrix are independent or not. Strang demonstrated that we can perform Gauss-Jordan Elimination with the joint matrix $[I | A]$, and the nullspace is simply the row in I that corresponds with any 0 rows in A.

However, I'm struggling to understand whether this method provides a unique solution or not. I understand that Gauss Elimination works by eliminating a dimension of all vectors using a row vector, eliminating as many dimensions of our matrix with as many possible row vectors as we have (row vector one, with pivot in position 1, eliminates all elements column 1 in the other vectors). However, while I understand that this produces a solution, I'm struggling to see why exactly this method works at guaranteeing a unique solution, whereby a row is written as the sum of some combination of vectors. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Honestly, I'm not sure I even understand why row reduction in this case allows us to determine independence. I can see that given a set of vectors, how we can write these as columns of a matrix and then perform row reduction to check for independence. In that case, we're really just solving the system of equations that the matrix represents. But I don't get why this really works when the vectors are written as rows of a matrix (the transpose of the earlier case).

Comment: You can always multiply a zero row by a scalar to find a different vector in the nullspace.

Comment: Yea I guess I should've included that. I want to call that a trivial alternate solution. But I mean anything that isn't just a scalar multiple of another vector, or another zero row added on to produce another vector. I mean a solution procured naturally by the method.

Comment: The nullspace is a vector space so it's closed under linear combinations.

Comment: Yep I agree. But why does this method of row reduction work in terms of producing the left null space? And does it always work?

Comment: No, the solution isn't unique. The non-zero rows that remain will form a basis of $A$ - and are be infinitely many basis' for a vector space $\mathbb{R}^n, n \ge 1$. Or I suppose the solution could be unique in the sense that the span of those vectors will always give the same space, the nullspace of $A$. Depends on the definition of "uniqueness".

Comment: Yes, the Gauss-Jordan method will always produce the nullspace of $A$. It's easy to see this if you think of $Ax=b$ as a system of linear equations. The Guass-Jordan elimination basically solves this system with the following $3$ operations: row swaps, adding $c$ times one equation to the other, and multiplying an equation by a $c\ne 0$ value. These are always valid ways to manipulate a system of equations. And at the end, it'll produce a solution, $x$, also known as the nullspace of $A$.

Comment: @Dude156 the identity matrix keeps track of which linear combinations of which rows you're adding and subtracting. So once you zero out the row the vector on the right has to be in the nullspace.

Comment: @CyclotomicField sure, but how are we to guarantee that if a 0 row could be reached, then it will actually be reached? Do you see what I'm asking here?

Comment: @DanielP my question is about reducing [I | A] to find the left null space. I'm wondering why exactly row reduction does not fail to 0 out a row if that row in A is a combination of other rows in A.

Comment: I'm going to re-ask this question with more clear formatting in the question. Will link that here and close this when done. Sorry for the confusion, I realize how unclear my question is.

Comment: New question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727280/basis-for-left-null-space-calculation