# Basis for Left Null Space Calculation

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the process of finding the left null space of some matrix A. This is equivalent to asking for the null space of the rows of the matrix, or:

$$
x^TA=0^T
$$

This is also equivalent to asking for $A^Tx=0$ (the nullspace of $A^T$).

Now, I understand how Gaussian Elimination can be used to solve for the x in the second equation. I also understand why this works in terms of row operations.

However, I became aware of a method to solve the nullspace of A^T directly from A. In this method, an identity matrix is pre-pended to the left of A and row reductions are done on both matrices. If a row of 0's is reached, then the corresponding row in the transformed I is a basis-vector for the left nullspace of A.

For example, let us consider the following 2x3 matrix:

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & -3 \\
-4 & 2 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Let us augment this matrix with I.
$$
[I|A] = \left[\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
1 & 0 & 2 & -1 & -3 \\
0 & 1 & -4 & 2 & 6
\end{array}\right]
$$

Now we row reduce.
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
1 & 0 & 2 & -1 & 3 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$

Thus, by looking at the row that corresponds to the zero row of the transformed A, we find that our solution $x^T = x_2 \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Now although I understand why this is a solution, I don't quite understand why the method of gauss Jordan was actually legal to apply here. In the case of $A^T$, I can see that row reductions merely correspond to adding the underlying linear equations represented by each row.

Secondly, I'm not sure I really understand why Gauss-Jordan is always able to produce a solution for the left null-space. Again, I understand this in the context of $A^T$, where we simply eliminate underlying variables, and then back substitute.

But in the context of the left nullspace I don't get how this method will always find a solution if there is one to be found. While this example was relatively simple, how can we guarantee that Gauss Jordan will actually always correctly eliminate a row which is a combination of other rows?

I hope my question is clear here. Please ask in comments, and I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's more common to put $I$ on the right since $[I \mid A]$ is already in row-echelon form. If you row reduce $[A \mid I]$, this is sometimes called the *extended row echelon form* and there's a [long description of it here](http://buzzard.ups.edu/papers/2014-extended-echelon-form/amer.math.monthly.121.07.644-beezer.pdf) ([paywalled DOI link](http://dx.doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.121.07.644)).

As to your question, when you row reduce $[A \mid I]$ that's equivalent to multiplying on the left by a sequence of elementary matrices. The whole process is the same as multiplying by the product of these matrices. Call that product $R$. You have:

$$
R \cdot [A \mid I] = [RA \mid R].
$$

Observe that $R$ is just whatever goes where you initially had $I$ and $RA$ is the row-echelon form of $A$. Also, observe that you have the equation

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & -3 \\ -4 & 2 & 6 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & -3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

On the left we have $RA$ but we know that $RA$ is just the row echelon form of $A$. If you go row-by-row, this is really two equations:

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & -3 \\ -4 & 2 & 6 \end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & -3 \end{bmatrix}, \\
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & -3 \\ -4 & 2 & 6 \end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

So you see that $[2, 1]$ belongs to the left-nullspace. If you count the pivots, you'll see that the number of non-pivot rows is equal to the number of left-nullspace vectors you get in $R$. Also, $R$ is invertible since it came from a product of elementary matrices. So the rows of $R$ are linearly independent. You can check the link for more information.

Comment: That is not really what I'm asking about. If our matrix has rows say r1, r2, r3, r4. Let's say that some combination of the first three equals r4. I am wondering why elimination is able to find that combination.

Comment: @Dude156 What part of the argument is unclear to you:
1. when you row reduce you get some pivots and some rows of 0
2. there are $\operatorname{rank} A$ rows with pivots and they are linearly independent so they are a basis for the row space of $A$
3. the rest of the rows are 0 and the corresponding rows in $R$ are linearly independent (since $R$ is invertible) and each one corresponds to a vector in the left-nullspace